# Split one column into multiple column on python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file from which I want to extract a segment which consists in a table. For doing that I read with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

sp= pd.read_table("spec3369.out")
a=sp.iloc[513: 4195]
```

This imports:

a

##############################################################
513     3663.00   -0.58576   0.43110    0.000   0.40723
514     3664.00   -0.46148   0.42810    0.000   0.40482
515     3665.00   -0.36138   0.42486    0.000   0.40234
516     3666.00   -0.28545   0.42203    0.000   0.40041
517     3667.00   -0.23368   0.41974    0.000   0.39898
...                                                 ...
4172    7322.00    0.96749   1.10490   14.444   1.14060
4173    7323.00    0.96061   1.10573   14.444   1.14153
4174    7324.00    0.96312   1.10644   14.444   1.14229
4175    7325.00    0.97502   1.10704   14.444   1.14287
4176    7326.00    0.99631   1.10766   14.444   1.14345

> [3664 rows x 1 columns]

Now I want to split the columns and add a header.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one line:

```
sp = pd.read_csv('spec3369.out', delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
```

Comment: yes, but my problem is that the original spec3369.out is not a table but a document. The table is at the final of the document in between the line 513 and 4195 (up to the end). I am working with a bunch of this kind of document of I am to recuperate these tables.